# How to list predictive values of associated categorical variables identified via Goodman-Kruskal's tau?

Tags: r, categorical-data

I have a dataset with purely categorical variables and used the GKtauDataframe() function of the GoodmanKruskal package in R to produce a matrix of associated variables. The package does not seem to support analyses of predictive values that cause these associations, however. I am a beginner in R, what is the most straightforward way to identify the predictive values?

I have examined functions of the package to check whether this information is actually stored somewhere but could not find any. Any hints, thoughts, links appreciated.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Do you know for a fact that statistical methods exist for analyzing the predictive values? If not, you may want to first get some statistical advice at [stats.se] to point you in the right direction.